# What did Rocket give Hawkeye in "Avengers: Endgame"?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame*, there was some object that Rocket gave Hawkeye just before the Avengers

> traveled to the past to retrieve the Infinity Stones.

and He made him promise to “bring it back in one piece” (which Hawkeye does albeit with very little enthusiasm). What was it?

Comment: Watch *Ant-Man* and you'll know exactly what it is.

Comment: @Harper I've seen _Ant-Man_

Comment: Then remember the miniature tank keychain?

Comment: @Harper Yeah, I remember. Problem is i simply didn't see what it was, hence the question is "What is it?" instead of "How was it shrinked?"

Answer (score 50, accepted):

It was a shrunken *Benatar*, the spaceship Widow and Hawkeye later used to travel to Vormir. Rocket, obviously, is attached to this ship - and in the absence of most of the other Guardians (Nebula's still new), he's got the responsibility on it, unofficially.

The ship was almost certainly shrunk with Ant-Man's shrinking disks.

Comment: So he shrunk an entire spaceship to a few cm and then someone took that with him when shrinking into the quantum handwavy area? I wonder how deep this process can go…

Comment: @FabianRöling It goes exactly as deep as the current scene of the current movie demands. Just like with the conservation of mass during shrinking and enlarging, it can and will vary wildly.

Comment: Maybe Pym particles can shrink other Pym particles ?

Comment: @PierreCathé they'd have to be able to, since Steve/Tony took some back with them to the present.

Comment: @Moira And everyone took the back to the past.

Comment: @FabianRöling Pym particles can shrink things as far as the plot demands.